# SQL if statement with two tables

Tags: sql, if-statement

Given the following tables:

table objects

```
id    Name   rating
1     Megan      9
2     Irina     10
3     Vanessa    7
4     Samantha   9
5     Roxanne    1
6     Sonia      8
```

swap table

```
id   swap_proposalid   counterpartyid
1                 4                2
2                 3                2
```

Everyone wants the ten. I would like to make a list for Irina of possible swaps where id 4 and 3 don't appear because the propositions are already there.

output1

```
id   Name    rating
1     Megan      9
5     Roxanne    1
6     Sonia      8
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of `counterpartyid`? I'm struggling to see how this design could support a scenario where `counterpartyid` contained more than one distinct value. Unless the "Everyone wants the ten" identifies the distinct value to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
SELECT mt2.ID, mt2.Name, mt2.Rating
FROM [MyTable] mt2  -- Other Candidates
   , [MyTable] mt1 -- Candidate / Subject (Irina)
WHERE mt2.ID NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT st.swap_proposalid
    FROM SwapTable st
    WHERE
      st.counterpartyid = mt1.ID
  )
AND mt1.ID <> mt2.ID -- Don't match Irina with Irina
AND mt1.Name = 'Irina' -- Find other swaps for Irina
```

-- Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  ID INT, 
  Name VARCHAR(100),
  Rating INT
)
GO
CREATE TABLE SwapTable
(
  ID INT,
  swap_proposalid INT,
  counterpartyid INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(1     ,'Megan',       9)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(2     ,'Irina',      10)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(3     ,'Vanessa',    7)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(4     ,'Samantha',   9)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(5     ,'Roxanne',    1)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(6     ,'Sonia',      8)

INSERT INTO SwapTable(ID, swap_proposalid, counterpartyid)
VALUES (1, 4, 2)
INSERT INTO SwapTable(ID, swap_proposalid, counterpartyid)
VALUES (1, 3, 2)
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the logic relating to "Everyone wants the ten".

Comment: OP mentioned 'I would like to make a list for Irina' so I had assumed that the selection of the '10' (Irina) had already happened. Also OP's desired output seems to implicitly imply only a single subject. counter_party_id seems to be subject (for whom the list is to be made, viz for Irina)

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT o.id, o.Name, o.rating 
FROM objects o
LEFT JOIN swap s on o.id = s.swap_proposalid
WHERE s.id IS NULL
AND o.Name != 'Irina'
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that the logic involves identifying the objects EXCEPT the highest rated object EXCEPT propositions with the highest rated object e.g. (using sample DDL and data kindly posted by @nonnb):

```
WITH ObjectHighestRated
     AS 
     (      
      SELECT ID
        FROM MyTable 
       WHERE Rating = (
                       SELECT MAX(T.Rating)
                         FROM MyTable T
                      )
     ),
     PropositionsForHighestRated
     AS
     (
      SELECT swap_proposalid AS ID
        FROM SwapTable
       WHERE counterpartyid IN (SELECT ID FROM ObjectHighestRated)
     ), 
     CandidateSwappersForHighestRated
     AS
     (
      SELECT ID
        FROM MyTable 
      EXCEPT 
      SELECT ID
        FROM ObjectHighestRated
      EXCEPT 
      SELECT ID
        FROM PropositionsForHighestRated                    
     )
SELECT * 
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CandidateSwappersForHighestRated);
```